# Add new rows before and after each gsm_id

Tags: python, pandas

I have data frame with  13 columns and 900 over rows.
I set one of the columns as index, which is the same for multiple events.
What i want to do is to add two new rows above the existing first row with 13 columns including that index and copy all the values from the present column.

How can i add it.

I want to add two new rows after the last row at each **gsm_id**

[image]

In the picture below, i want to add a new row before the first row and after the last row. **gsm_id** is set to index and i will  add new rows before and after each **gsm_id**

My expected output will be as follow highlighted in red.
[image]
Thanks
Zep

Comment: Can you explain more? What is excected output?

Comment: Hi Jez,
Thanks for getting into this.
I have uploaded the expected output which is highlighted in Red.
Evendatetime of the last two rows highlighted in red is just 90 minutes plus matchdatetime.
thank you in advanace.

Comment: Sorry, still dont understand. first row is clear - same as first column of first row of group, only difference `Team_SR` and `Match` last column. But last 2 rows are a bit unclear - how you get these times? I try subtract 90 minutes from last row of data and no luck.

Comment: Hi Jez,
Eventdatetime in last two rows is basically matchdatetime plus 90 minutes. i.e. eventdatetime in the last two rows will be 8/11/2018 20:15. (it is not 20:20, my typo error). Sorry about that.

Comment: This question is really unclear, perhaps to me. In addition: Do you really need 13 columns to make a minimal example for this question? Why use images?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
#create new column for last sorting
df['sort'] = df.groupby('gsm_id').cumcount() + 2

#get first 2 rows per each group
df1 = df.groupby('gsm_id').head(2).copy()

#modify values
df1[['PreviousEventTime','Goal_Flag','Union_level']] = np.nan
df1[['Run_score','Run_sum']] = 0
df1['Match_sta'] = 'Started'
#subtract for 0,1 values - first rows per groups
df1['sort'] -= 2
#print (df1)

#get last 2 rows per groups
df2 = df.groupby('gsm_id').tail(2).copy()
#change datetimes
df2['eventdatetime'] = df2['matchdatetime'] + pd.Timedelta(90, unit='m')
#add 2 for last 2 rows
df2['sort'] += 2
#print (df2)

#join all together and sort for correct ordering
df = (pd.concat([df1, df2, df])
        .sort_values(['gsm_id','sort'])
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .drop('sort', axis=1))
print (df)
```

---

```
print (df)

     gsm_id    comp       ht         at team       matchdatetime  \
0   2462794   EngPr  Arsenal  Leicester    A 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
1   2462794   EngPr  Arsenal  Leicester    L 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
2   2462794   EngPr  Arsenal  Leicester    A 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
3   2462794   EngPr  Arsenal  Leicester    L 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
4   2462794   EngPr  Arsenal  Leicester    A 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
5   2462794   EngPr  Arsenal  Leicester    L 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
6   2462794   EngPr  Arsenal  Leicester    A 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
7   2462794   EngPr  Arsenal  Leicester    L 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
8   2462794   EngPr  Arsenal  Leicester    A 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
9   2462795  EngPr1  Arsenal  Leicester    A 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
10  2462795  EngPr1  Arsenal  Leicester    L 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
11  2462795  EngPr1  Arsenal  Leicester    A 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
12  2462795  EngPr1  Arsenal  Leicester    L 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
13  2462795  EngP1r  Arsenal  Leicester    A 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
14  2462795  EngP1r  Arsenal  Leicester    L 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
15  2462795  EngPr1  Arsenal  Leicester    A 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
16  2462795  EngP1r  Arsenal  Leicester    L 2017-08-11 18:45:00   
17  2462795  EngPr1  Arsenal  Leicester    A 2017-08-11 18:45:00   

         eventdatetime   PreviousEventTime   Goal_Flag Union_level Team_SR  \
0  2017-08-11 18:46:00                 NaT         NaN         NaN       A   
1  2017-08-11 18:49:00                 NaT         NaN         NaN       L   
2  2017-08-11 18:46:00 2017-08-11 18:45:00  First Goal      Scored       A   
3  2017-08-11 18:49:00 2017-08-11 18:46:00  First Goal    Conceded       L   
4  2017-08-11 19:13:00 2017-08-11 18:49:00  Other Goal      Scored       A   
5  2017-08-11 19:31:00 2017-08-11 19:13:00   Last Goal      Scored       A   
6  2017-08-11 19:40:00 2017-08-11 19:31:00   Last Goal    Conceded       L   
7  2017-08-11 20:15:00 2017-08-11 19:13:00   Last Goal      Scored       A   
8  2017-08-11 20:15:00 2017-08-11 19:31:00   Last Goal    Conceded       L   
9  2017-08-11 18:46:00                 NaT         NaN         NaN       A   
10 2017-08-11 18:49:00                 NaT         NaN         NaN       L   
11 2017-08-11 18:46:00 2017-08-11 18:45:00  First Goal      Scored       A   
12 2017-08-11 18:49:00 2017-08-11 18:46:00  First Goal    Conceded       L   
13 2017-08-11 19:13:00 2017-08-11 18:49:00  Other Goal      Scored       A   
14 2017-08-11 19:31:00 2017-08-11 19:13:00   Last Goal      Scored       A   
15 2017-08-11 19:40:00 2017-08-11 19:31:00   Last Goal    Conceded       L   
16 2017-08-11 20:15:00 2017-08-11 19:13:00   Last Goal      Scored       A   
17 2017-08-11 20:15:00 2017-08-11 19:31:00   Last Goal    Conceded       L   

    Run_score  Run_sum Match_sta  
0           0        0   Started  
1           0        0   Started  
2           1        1   Winning  
3          -1       -1    Losing  
4           1        1   Winning  
5           1        1   Winning  
6          -1       -1    Losing  
7           1        1   Winning  
8          -1       -1    Losing  
9           0        0   Started  
10          0        0   Started  
11          1        1   Winning  
12         -1       -1    Losing  
13          1        1   Winning  
14          1        1   Winning  
15         -1       -1    Losing  
16          1        1   Winning  
17         -1       -1    Losing
```

Sample data:

```
c = ['gsm_id', 'comp', 'ht', 'at', 'team', 'matchdatetime','eventdatetime', 'PreviousEventTime', 'Goal_Flag', 'Union_level', 'Team_SR', 'Run_score', 'Run_sum', 'Match_sta']
df = pd.DataFrame({'Team_SR': ['A', 'L', 'A', 'A', 'L', 'A', 'L', 'A', 'A', 'L'], 
'team': ['A', 'L', 'A', 'L', 'A', 'A', 'L', 'A', 'L', 'A'], 
'matchdatetime': [pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:45:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:45:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:45:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:45:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:45:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:45:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:45:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:45:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:45:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:45:00')], 
'at': ['Leicester', 'Leicester', 'Leicester', 'Leicester', 'Leicester', 'Leicester', 'Leicester', 'Leicester', 'Leicester', 'Leicester'], 
'Union_level': ['Scored', 'Conceded', 'Scored', 'Scored', 'Conceded', 'Scored', 'Conceded', 'Scored', 'Scored', 'Conceded'], 
'Run_score': [1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1], 
'eventdatetime': [pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:46:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:49:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 19:13:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 19:31:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 19:40:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:46:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:49:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 19:13:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 19:31:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 19:40:00')], 
'ht': ['Arsenal', 'Arsenal', 'Arsenal', 'Arsenal', 'Arsenal', 'Arsenal', 'Arsenal', 'Arsenal', 'Arsenal', 'Arsenal'], 
'Match_sta': ['Winning', 'Losing', 'Winning', 'Winning', 'Losing', 'Winning', 'Losing', 'Winning', 'Winning', 'Losing'], 
'gsm_id': [2462794, 2462794, 2462794, 2462794, 2462794, 2462795, 2462795, 2462795, 2462795, 2462795],
'Goal_Flag': ['First Goal', 'First Goal', 'Other Goal', 'Last Goal', 'Last Goal', 'First Goal', 'First Goal', 'Other Goal', 'Last Goal', 'Last Goal'], 'Run_sum': [1, -1, 1, 1, -1, 1, -1, 1, 1, -1], 
'comp': ['EngPr', 'EngPr', 'EngPr', 'EngPr', 'EngPr', 'EngPr1', 'EngPr1', 'EngP1r', 'EngP1r', 'EngPr1'], 'PreviousEventTime': [pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:45:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:46:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:49:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 19:13:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 19:31:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:45:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:46:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 18:49:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 19:13:00'), pd.Timestamp('2017-08-11 19:31:00')]}, columns=c)
```

Comment: Thanks Jez,
Your advice is greatly helpful and really appreciate it.
I have some issue with sorting because gsm_id is set to index in my coding from the beginning.
therefore, i reset index using:
`df.reset_index()
df1.reset_index()
df2.reset_index()`
When i do the concat, it gives me key error: 'gsm_id'